# Tengo tres listas y no sé concatenarla en un cierto orden

Tags: python, lista, tuplas

espero que puedan responderme:

Tengo 3 listas:

```
lista1=[Pepe, Juan, Manolo, Pablo]
lista2=[23,28,27,32]
lista3=[190,164,154,175]
```

Edit: De manera que consiguese una lista de cadenas

```
["Pepe,23,190 ", "Juan,28,164",...]
```

Lista 1 es el nombre, lista 2 la edad y lista 3 la altura en cm.
¿Cómo podría encadenarlo de manera que fuera: " Pepe,23,190 "...?
Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Hola, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]. Sería bueno que agregaras lo que has intentado para mostrar  investigación previa, que no funcione es irrelevante. Por otro lado, ¿qué salida esperas?¿Una lista de listas `[["Pepe", 23, 190], "Juan", 28, 164],...]`?¿Una lista de cadenas `["Pepe,23,190 ", "Juan,28,164",...]`? ¿Solo imprimir?¿generar un archivo csv?¿otra cosa? Sea como sea, `zip()` es la respuesta...

Comment: Buenas y gracias por responder. Yo sé lo básico, haciendo la suma de las listas, pero no con un orden específico. Me gustaría saber cómo se podría hacer de modo de lista de cadenas aunque de la otra manera tampoco estaría mal. Gracias de antemano y siento mi desconocimiento, estoy recién empezando en esto de programación .

Answer (score 0):

Si las 3 listas siempre son de la misma longitud:

```
res = []
for i in range(len(lista1)):
    res.append(f'{lista1[i]},{lista2[i]},{lista3[i]}')
```

La variable `res` es la lista resultante.

Comment: Gracias, muchas gracias! :D

Answer (score 0):

"Sumar" las listas, es decir concatenarlas, no resuelve el problema, solo conseguimos una lista de la forma:

```
[Pepe, Juan, Manolo, Pablo, 23, 28, 27, 32, 190, 164, 154, 175]
```

lo que se aleja aún más de lo que buscamos.

La solución pasa por iterar a la par sobre las tres listas y la forma más eficente y simple es usar `zip` junto a `str.join` para generar la cadena:

```
lista1 = ["Pepe", "Juan", "Manolo", "Pablo"]
lista2 = [23, 28, 27, 32]
lista3 = [190, 164, 154, 175]

lista_cadenas = [
    ",".join(str(item) for item in items)
        for items in zip(lista1,  lista2,  lista3)
        ]
```

> ```
> >>> lista_cadenas   
> ['Pepe,23,190', 'Juan,28,164', 'Manolo,27,154', 'Pablo,32,175']
> ```

El código funcionará independientemente del número de listas o iterables que tengamos, basta con agregarlos a `zip`.

Una versión más simple, pero limitada a tres iterables (modificando el literal de cadena formateado se puede modificar no obstante):

```
lista_cadenas = [f"{a},{b},{c}" for a, b, c in zip(lista1, lista2, lista3)]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Todavía me queda por estudiar ya que esto es un poco complejo para mí jejeje. Gracias